# Python how to get XML Namespace using etree

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, elementtree

I have no chance to access the namespace definitions in Python
using `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

Attributes of the RootElement:

```
xmlns="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
test="xxx"
```

rootElemt.attrib only contains the attribute "test" the ns-definitions are ignored by the parser.

I have already written a lot of functions that work with Etree.elements so switching to another type is the last option.

I know that lxml is capable of getting the Namespaces
but Im scared of using it because I don't want to install the dependencys 
on the users computer.

Is there another lib that is capable of doing this job.

thanks